# Using absolute path in Angular 2 + Electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, fs

I started messing around with Angular 2 and Electron, and used [this starter package](https://github.com/jkuri/angular-electron-starter). Everything seems to be going well, I'm even able to use the node fs package to read from a directory.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to be able to use an absolute path for the readdirSync() method. It only takes a relative path.

I did find this in the [docs for fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) that you can use the URL package to show an absolute path for readdirSync(), like so:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { URL } = require('url');

// file:///C:/tmp/hello => C:\tmp\hello
fs.readFileSync(new URL('file:///C:/tmp/hello'));
```

That looks great, but in my Angular 2/TypeScript/Electron world that doesn't seem to work. Mine looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {readdirSync} from "fs";
import { URL } from "url";


@Injectable()
export class LinkDocRetrieverService {
    getFiles():Array<String> {

        // read through all the directories to get all the files and folder names

        let u = new URL("file:///C:/SAFE/MISC");
        let x = readdirSync(u);
        console.log("files retrieved="+ x.length);

        let files: Array<string> = [];
        x.forEach(f => {
            files.push(f);
        });
        return files;
    }
}
```

Both intellisense and runtime both tell me that

> [ts] Argument of type 'URL' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string | Buffer'.   Type 'URL' is not assignable to type 'Buffer'.
>       Property 'write' is missing in type 'URL'.

I would have expected the syntax to be the same, but no luck.

I have read a lot of posts stating that they can't run the fs package in Angular 2 + Typescript, but it works well for me, as long as I use a relative path. I just need help getting the absolute path to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_whatwg_url_object_support) states that URL support was introduced in v7.6.0 and is experimental. Electron uses v7.4.0, thus you can not use URL with fs yet.

```
fs.readFileSync('C:/tmp/hello')
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: in my case it looks like: let x = readdirSync("C:/SAFE/MISC");